# How to implement Alexnet like data augmentation in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'd like to achieve AlexNet like validation data augmentation. It goes by cropping 4 edges plus center of tha image and flipping each one horizontally, resulting in 10 crops. For now, keras data augmentation only takes an image and returns an image. I could use preprocessing function but it'll still yield one image. I could also create the set before hand the training but don't wanna do that. Are there any ways to implement this on the run time like pytorchs' `torchvision.transforms.TenCrop`